# MP3 getting mixed up

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, mp3

I am running ICS on my tablet.

Whenever I copy new music files to my tablet, the files get mixed (playing parts of other music files for 5,6 seconds randomly in any file I copied). What should I do?

Comment: Most music players do not separate music files by folders. You will need to manually create a playlist in order for you to play a group of files you want.

Comment: Do you mean to say that the music doesn't start from beginning of each file and doesn't end at its end. Instead the play starts somewhere from middle of the file, plays for a while and jumps to some other file?

Answer (score 0):

If you are saving music files to SD card, it may be the problem of the SD card. Change the SD card and try.

Good Luck.